# linear functional and sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis

Let $E$ be a normed vector space and consider a sequence $\left(x_{n}\right) \in E$ such that for each $\phi \in E^{\prime}$ the

sequence $\left(\phi\left(x_{n}\right)\right)$ is convergent in $\mathbb{R}$. Then $\left(x_{n}\right)$
is bounded in $E$

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Define a functionals $$\xi_n : X' \to \mathbb{R} ,$$

$$\xi_n (f) = f(x_n ). $$

We have $$||\xi_n ||=\sup\{ |\xi_n (f) |: ||f||=1\} =\sup\{ |f(x_n )| : ||f||=1\}=||x_n||.$$
Hence we obtain a sequence of functionals $(\xi_n )$ from Banach space $X'$ to a Banach space $\mathbb{R}$ that converges for every $f\in X'.$ Therefore by Banach-Steinhaus theorem the sequence $(||\xi_n ||)=(||x_n ||)$$ is bounded.